# How to not accept query parameters from a post request in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, request, postman

I am doing a login via api using postman. But I noticed that it also accepts the query parameters when using POST method. I am not sure if this is the default way the Request works in Laravel so I would like to get some idea on how can I avoid on getting the data if it's being passed as query parameters. Basically I only want to process the login via api if the data is coming from the post body.

Thanks!

Comment: use validation/validate method. Then you'd only get the validated fields to hit Auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access only the parameters from `query string` by:

```php
$request->query();
```

Similarly, you can access only the parameters from `body` by:

```php
$request->post();
```